# change label color radio when checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

im having problem on how to change the color of label text for the radio button to blue color after the radio is checked. I've followed many sample code but it wont work.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label for="pickup-1" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>  
   <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
     <input id="pickup-1" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change your HTML structure a little bit & use **`~`** ([General Sibling Combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)) selector, like:

```
.radio-custom:checked ~ label {
  color: blue;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.radio-custom:checked ~ label {
  color: blue;
}

label {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-group {
  display: block;
}

.text-group-field {
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
     <div class="inner-block">
       <input id="pickup-1" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
       <label for="pickup-1" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
     <div class="inner-block">
       <input id="pickup-2" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
       <label for="pickup-2" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
     <div class="inner-block">
       <input id="pickup-3" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
       <label for="pickup-3" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3103783 Have a look at my updated answer. By just using CSS you can achieve this. Have a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: @user3103783 Have a look at my answer, Its as it is according to your screenshot. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: @user3103783 It's my pleasure. I've updated the code with `flexbox`, now it is much easier to achieve.

Comment: u p v o t e d - as it solved my problem. In my case I need only `.radio-custom:checked ~ label`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Works for all radio buttons having class `radio-custom`. Sets `blue` color only to selected radio button label.

```js
window.onload = function () {
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".radio-custom"), function (el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".radio-custom-label"), function(label){
    label.style.color = "black";
   });

   document.querySelector("label[for='" + this.id + "']").style.color = "blue";
  });
 });
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
 <label for="pickup-1" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>
 <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
  <input id="pickup-1" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
 <label for="pickup-2" class="radio-custom-label">11.00 PM</label>
 <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
  <input id="pickup-2" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've follow your code. The label change to blue. but when i try to checked the 2nd radio button the 1st radio button will stay in blue color.

Comment: `[].forEach.call` is an unwanted hack. The code is not reusable and it create vulnerabilities

Comment: @brk `[].forEach.call is an unwanted hack` : Any other solution you propose without using forEach/for loop. I would like to know.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM you can take a look at this
https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Comment: @brk Thanks... will go through the link.

Answer (score 0):

Add `change` event to the radio button.On that event , get the `label` tag matches with the `id` of the radio. using `document.querySelector` , then add a css class to the element

```js
document.getElementById('pickup-1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('label[for="pickup-1"]').classList.add('colorText')
})
```

```css
.colorText {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <label for="pickup-1" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>
  <div class="text-group-field pickup-day choose-time">
    <input id="pickup-1" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the radio button is more than 1? can i use class instead of using ID to change the color?

Comment: No you cannot use that, the question does not tells about the possibility of more than one radio button. But this function can be slightly tweaked to accommodate that functionality

Answer (score 0):

A result much closer to your reference image.

**[check out here](https://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/s3x5ormu/1/)**

```
<div class="input-group">


 <input id="pickup-1" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
 <label for="pickup-1" class="radio-custom-label">10.00 PM</label>

 <input id="pickup-2" class="radio-custom input-group-field" name="radio-group" type="radio">
 <label for="pickup-2" class="radio-custom-label">20.00 PM</label>

</div>
```

and the css

```
.input-group{
 background: #323447;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 input[type=radio]{
  display: none;
 }

.radio-custom-label{
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 display: block;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 color:#ddd;
 font-weight: 600;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .radio-custom-label::after{
  width:15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position:relative;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: none;
  }

  input[type=radio]:checked+.radio-custom-label::after{
  display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input:checked + label{
    color: @grey !important;
    background-color: @white !important;
    border-color: @white !important;
}
```