# How to select radio buttons with click to change color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a math quiz game for my classroom. I have created a page to select the type of game the user wants. I have created a function to select the the element when it is clicked to change colors but it is not changing colors. I have tried to hard code the styling and it works properly but I only want the styling when the radio container is selected.

```js
const startForm = document.getElementById('start-form');
const radioContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-container');
const radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const bestScores = document.querySelectorAll('.best-score-value');

startForm.addEventListener('click', () => {
  radioContainers.forEach((radioEl) => {
    radioEl.classList.remove('selected-label');
    if (radioEl.childeren[1].checked) {
      radioEl.classList.add('selected-label');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
RADIO CONTAINER TO BE SELECTED
<div class="radio-container">
  <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
  <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99">
  <span class="best-score">
                            <span>Best Score</span>
  <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and have your code snippet working

Comment: I made you a snippet. You are missing some HTML and CSS

Comment: `childeren`  is misspelled

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this

Delegation from startForm is fine, then we can loop over the divs to see if the radio in the div was checked

```js
const startForm = document.getElementById('start-form');
const radioContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-container');

startForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.name === "Questions") {
    const parent = tgt.closest('.radio-container')
    radioContainers.forEach(container => container.classList.toggle('selected-label', container === parent && tgt.checked))
  }
});
```

```css
.selected-label { color: green }
```

```html
<form id="start-form">
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Im not sure if i didnt show enough code or not but this is not working. I have a selected-label style in my index.css. Is my html code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Question is somewhat a duplicate.
[change label color radio when checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901698/change-label-color-radio-when-checked)
I got the answer from here, and it can be done using CSS without needing to use JavaScript.
(Notice some buttons have different colors when clicked)
Here's a snippet

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span
{
color:red;

}

input[type="radio"]:checked.correct ~ span
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<form id="start-form">
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99" class = "correct">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="value-99">99 Questions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Questions" value="99" id="value-99" class = "correct">
    <span class="best-score">Best Score</span>
    <span class="best-score-value">0.0</span>
  </div>
</form>
```